# Osmdroid disable map rotation

Tags: android, osmdroid

I can't find informations. Is there a possibility to disable user to rotate map? Sometimes when I make gesture I loose North. I would like to disable this at all or make some button to rotate user from rotated map to north.

Any tips?

Comment: Is there a [RotationGestureOverlay](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocAll/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/gestures/RotationGestureOverlay.html) and can't you just remove it or maybe call a method like `setEnabled(false)` on it?